# CreateBodyFromBox3 boxAxis vector issues

Tags: api, macros, solidworks

I am using CreateBodyFromBox3 to create a set of bodies for a macro feature and one needs to be put at an angle about the z axis. I can set the extrusion vector so it is at an angle about X or Y without any issues but if its about Z the vector that is normal to the extrusion detection obviously has a Z component. The shape is correct so I know all the other values in the array are correct and the body is created without any errors.

Any ideas for a workaround? I have tried to use transforms and i am able to get the transforms array data into an Variant, but when I put try to make the transforms array data equal to the Variant it just resets the Variant back to the original array data.

(The Coordinate System shown is the same as the model space Coordinate System)

[Rotated about X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zHGB.png)  

`dblData(3) = 0
dblData(4) = 0.5
dblData(5) = -0.866`

[Rotated about Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft959.png)

`dblData(3) = 0.5
dblData(4) = -0.866
dblData(5) = 0`

Comment: possibly the code you have already tried may help us get you something that may work

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I never did get the vector portions of the array to work and just ended up using transforms, which the API help is not terribly clear on when it comes to using on bodies vs. components of features but it seems to work the same.

(Some of this might not look kosher, but the formatting on here was giving me trouble so I had to shuffle some things around.)

```
Public Sub CreateBody(bInsert As Boolean)
Dim swWorkBody As SldWorks.Body2, swToolBody1 As SldWorks.Body2
Dim swToolBody2 As SldWorks.Body2
Dim swTempBody_1 As SldWorks.Body2, swTempBody_2 As SldWorks.Body2
Dim swModeler As SldWorks.Modeler
Dim swFaultEnt As SldWorks.FaultEntity
Dim swTransform As SldWorks.MathTransform
Dim swMathUtil As SldWorks.MathUtility, vTransform As Variant
Dim swMoveBody As SldWorks.MoveCopyBodyFeatureData

Dim dblData(8) As Double
Dim vBody As Variant
Dim lngErr As Long
Dim Y As Double, theta As Double, pi As Double
Dim bRet As Boolean
Dim bReRet As Boolean

On Error GoTo errH
If bInsert = True Then GetMetric 
pi = 4 * Atn(1)
theta = Atn(mRoofSlope / (12 * m)) ' * (pi / 180)
Y = (mWidth - (2 * (mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth))) * Tan(theta)

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModeler = swApp.GetModeler
Set swMathUtil = swApp.GetMathUtility

dblData(0) = 0  'X Center
dblData(1) = 0  'Y Center
dblData(2) = 0  'Z Center
dblData(3) = 0  'X Direction Vector
dblData(4) = 1  'Y Direction Vector
dblData(5) = 0  'Z Direction Vector
dblData(8) = mHight + Y  'Hight of Extrution along Y

'Hollow Out Ext Walls
    'Make Tool Body
        dblData(6) = mWidth - (2 * (mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth))   'Width of Extrution along X
        dblData(7) = mLength - (2 * (mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth))  'Length of Extrution along Z

        Set swToolBody1 = swModeler.CreateBodyFromBox3(dblData)
        Set swFaultEnt = swToolBody1.Check3
        ProcessFaultEntity swApp, swModel, swFaultEnt

    'Make Work Pice Body
        dblData(6) = mWidth   'Width of Extrution along X
        dblData(7) = mLength  'Length of Extrution along Z

        Set swWorkBody = swModeler.CreateBodyFromBox3(dblData)
        Set swFaultEnt = swWorkBody.Check3
        ProcessFaultEntity swApp, swModel, swFaultEnt

        vBody = swWorkBody.Operations2(SWBODYCUT, swToolBody1, lngErr)
        Set swTempBody_1 = vBody(0)

'Create Low Side Walls
    'Make Tool Body
        dblData(0) = (mWidth / 2) - ((mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth) / 2)   'X Center
        dblData(1) = dblData(8) - Y                                         'Y Center
        dblData(6) = mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth                          'Width of Extrution along X
        dblData(8) = Y                                                      'Hight of Extrution along Y

        Set swToolBody1 = swModeler.CreateBodyFromBox3(dblData)
        Set swFaultEnt = swToolBody1.Check3
        ProcessFaultEntity swApp, swModel, swFaultEnt

        vBody = swTempBody_1.Operations2(SWBODYCUT, swToolBody1, lngErr)
        Set swTempBody_2 = vBody(0)

    'Create B&D Wall Slop
        dblData(0) = 0  'X Center
        dblData(1) = 0  'Y Center
        dblData(2) = 0  'Z Center
    '=============== This is were I was trying to use the vector method ==========
    '=============== I was just using 30 degrees so i could see it ===============
        dblData(3) = 0.5
        dblData(4) = -0.866
        dblData(5) = 0
    '========================================================================
        dblData(6) = mWidth - 2 * (mExtWallDepth + mIntWallDepth) + (Y * Tan(theta)) / 2 'Width of Extrution along X
        dblData(7) = mLength     'Length of Extrution along Z

        Set swToolBody2 = swModeler.CreateBodyFromBox3(dblData)
        Set swFaultEnt = swToolBody2.Check3
        ProcessFaultEntity swApp, swModel, swFaultEnt

  '======================== This is the fix ========================
        bRet = swToolBody2.GetCoincidenceTransform2(swToolBody2, swTransform)
        vTransform = swTransform.ArrayData

        vTransform(0) = Cos(theta)
        vTransform(1) = -Sin(theta)
        vTransform(2) = 0
        vTransform(3) = Sin(theta)
        vTransform(4) = Cos(theta)
        vTransform(5) = 0
        vTransform(6) = 0
        vTransform(7) = 0
        vTransform(8) = 1
        vTransform(9) = 0
        vTransform(10) = (mHight + Y / 2)
        vTransform(11) = 0

        swTransform.ArrayData = vTransform
        vTransform = swTransform.ArrayData
        bReRet = swToolBody2.ApplyTransform(swTransform)
        vBody = swTempBody_2.Operations2(SWBODYCUT, swToolBody2, lngErr)
'========================================================================    
'Set to Macro Body
Set swHouseBody = vBody(0)   'Set to Final Body

If STATE <> 0 Then swHouseBody.Display3 swModel, 255, 0
swModel.ViewZoomtofit

Exit Sub
errH:
Debug.Print "lngErr: " & lngErr
Debug.Print "Err Number: " & Err.Number
Debug.Print "Err Description: " & Err.Description
Err.Clear
Set swFaultEnt = Nothing
Set swWorkBody_1 = Nothing
Set swWorkBody_2 = Nothing
Set swToolBody1 = Nothing
Set swToolBody2 = Nothing
Set swHouseBody = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFaultEntity(swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks, swModel As             SldWorks.ModelDoc2, swFaultEnt As SldWorks.FaultEntity)
Dim nCount As Long
Dim swEnt As SldWorks.Entity
Dim bRet As Boolean
Dim i  As Long
nCount = swFaultEnt.Count: If 0 = nCount Then Exit Sub 'Else print the error code for each fault
For i = 0 To nCount - 1
    Set swEnt = swFaultEnt.Entity(i)
    If Not swEnt Is Nothing Then
        bRet = swEnt.Select4(True, Nothing): Debug.Assert bRet
    End If
    Debug.Print "    Fault[" & i & "] = " & swFaultEnt.ErrorCode(i)
Next i
End Sub
```